# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page

Tags: jsp, nullpointerexception

I deployed my jsp web application on jelastic using tomcat server 7 and Mysql. My code was working fine on my local server but after i deployed it on jelastic it is giving following error:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing
>   JSP page /loginService.jsp at line 11
>
> 8:        String error = null; 9:         String sql = "SELECT * FROM
>   login_details WHERE user_id='"+user_id+"'"; 10:                  11:
>         ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(sql); 12:
>         if(result.next()){ 13:
>             if(result.getString("password").contentEquals(password)){ 14:
>                 session.setAttribute("user_session_id", user_id);
>
> Stacktrace:
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728) root
>   cause
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>     org.apache.jsp.loginService_jsp._jspService(loginService_jsp.java:91)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

Comment: Got any code you can show us.. namely the lines specified in the exception report.

Comment: String sql = "SELECT * FROM login_details WHERE user_id='"+user_id+"'";
                
ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(sql);
  if(result.next()){

Comment: What is "statement". Do you ever initialize it?

Comment: i have initialized statement and created connection to database in another file that i have included in this file at top

Comment: `result.getString("password")` Are you sure this exists?

Comment: 100% actually its is working fine on my local server but causing problem only after deploying it

Comment: I see. Perhaps the issue is in your networking configuration then.. which I'm afraid isn't a programming issue.

Comment: and also i am getting exception on line `11: ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(sql); `

Comment: can you tell me how deal with is problem....... btw thank u very much for your suggestions and time..

Comment: Can you specify the type of exception you're getting on line 11?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: No doubt, it's because statement has not been initialised properly. This is probably linked to the issue with your network.